# JavaScript and jQuery, "this" inside an anonymos function

Tags: javascript, closures, this, anonymous-function

I have this code:

```
PageList: function(url, index, classes){
    this.url = url;
    this.index = index;
    ...
};

PageList.prototype.toHTML = function(){
    var div = $('<div class="container"></div>');
    var p = $('<p></p>');
    var link = $('<a></a>');
    $.each(this.elements, function(index, array_value){
          console.log(this.url);
          ...
    }
}
```

And it worked as expected.

The problem was that `console.log(this.url)` was printing `undefined`, so I reworked the code to look like this:

```
PageList.prototype.toHTML = function(){
    var div = $('<div class="container"></div>');
    var p = $('<p></p>');
    var link = $('<a></a>');
    var instance = this;
    $.each(this.elements, function(index, array_value){
               console.log(instance.url);
        }
}
```

I know that the problem was on the closure not taking `this` as the value of the instance, but as far as i know a reference to `this` inside a function that doesn't have an instance bound to it must refer to the window object, instead of `undefined`, at least that's the case on many of the browsers out there.

So what exactly is going on on my code.

Note: I'm using jQuery and `this.elements` is already defined.

Edit: Now im figuring out that `$.each` is a non-instance function, so my callback is being called from `$.each` but it must be `window` the reference to `this`, still thinking about it.

Comment: Welcome to the world of JavaScript scoping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for `$.each`:

> The value *[of the current element]* can also be accessed through the `this` keyword...

In JavaScript, when you hand off a callback function to a [higher-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) (in this case, `$.each`), the higher-order function can decide what the value of `this` will be when the callback runs. There is no way for you to control this behavior -- simply don't use `this` (e.g., by using a reference like `instance` in your example or via a closure).

Check out the context-setting functions [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to understand how a higher-order function like `$.each` sets the `this` context of a callback.  Once you read those MDN pages, it might clear a few things up.

Here's a quick example:

```
Array.prototype.forEachWithContext(callback, this_in_callback) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
        callback.call(this_in_callback, i, this[i]);
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
PageList.prototype.toHTML = function(){
    //...
    this.elements.forEachWithCallback(function(index, array_value){ ... }, this);
}
```

My example `Array.forEachWithContext` is similar to `Array.forEach`.  However, it takes a callback *and* a second argument that is used as the value of `this` during the execution each of those callbacks.

Comment: I know how to use call and apply, just it would be awkward to code some thing like this: $.each.apply(this, ... ); personaly i don't like to mix jquery and js on the same command like this.

Comment: You don't need to use my code -- I just wrote it exaplain how jQuery uses `call` to alter the context of your callback.  In this case, `$.each` is perfectly servicible; just use the code with `instance` you already have.  Since you know `call`/`apply`, the main value of my answer is the initial quote from the jQuery docs: **within the `$.each` callback, `this` is set to the current array element**.  That's the explanation you wanted, I think.

Comment: You were right, i watched an "object" on the console and assumed it was refering to the window object.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your `$.each` function with a `$.proxy` like this...

```
$.each(this.elements, $.proxy(function(index, array_value){
    console.log(this.url);
},this));
```

The `$.proxy` will ensure that `this` references your `PageList`...

Comment: Vote up for the proxy function, but still don't know what is causing it to behave like that.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that the problem was on the closure not taking this as the value of the instance, but as far as i know a reference to this inside a function that doesn't have an instance bound to it must refer to the window object, instead of undefined, at least that's the case on many of the browsers out there.

`this` *is* `window`. You're printing `window.url`, which is undefined. Try `console.log(this)`, and it should yield `window`.

Comment: It's pretty embatassing not to have notice that before.

Comment: Wait, is this correct?  My intuition (and tests) indicate that `this` should be equal to the `PageList` instance while inside of `PageList.toHTML` and then equal to the current list element while inside the callback to `$.each`.  When do you ever observe it being equal to `window` in this code, except outside of PageList altogether?

Comment: I just read @apsillers answer, and he may be right. But what is `this.elements` on your code?

Comment: So I guess @apsillers is right. I glanced at the docs before answering looking for that, didn't see it and assumed only [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) (as opposed to [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)) behaved that way. Anyway, I guess none of the values on the `elements` array has an `url` property, thus your `undefined` value.

Comment: They don't have a url property, url belongs to PageList instance, and that whas my first intention, to access the outer this.url.